# Excel lookup to assign level based on Age and Weight

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table of some 5,000 players with their age and weight.  I have a level table where I have created the max weight for each age and assigned a level.  The arrays in the lookup table are named 'Age', 'Weight', and 'Level" appropriately. The weight listed is the maximum for that age at that level, if the player's weight is over that they should go up to the next level. I have the lookup table below.  The player's age is in column E and their weight is in column K.

I need help with the lookup function that would assign the level to the player.

```
    Max   
Age Weight  Level
7   110     A
8   105     A
9   65      A
8   150     B
9   120     B
10  115     B
11  75      B
10  175     C
11  130     C
12  125     C
13  85      C
11  175     D
12  135     D
13  130     D
14  100     D
12  180     E
13  185     E
14  300     E
```

This is what I have tried:

`=INDEX(level,AND(MATCH(E2,age,0),MATCH(K2,weight,1)))`

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? I think you'll want to start with a `vlookup`

Comment: Fair question, I added to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically trying a VLOOKUP in two dimensions.
There are several ways to make that work, here's a simple one:

1. Add a column to your lookup table where you concatenate age and weight, preferably with a separator, so you get `07-105`, `08-105`, `09-065`, and so on. (Make both parts fixed width!)
2. Use VLOOKUP() into that column, and looking up the equivalent concatenation of the actual data.

You will need to sort the lookup table by the concatenated column.

If your data is the upper limit, and not the lower, you need to concatenate with the next row's value minus 1. For example, if you do a VLOOKUP("08-110",table,2;FALSE) in this table,

`08-105 A
08-120 B
08-150 C`

it will give you A, but you want B, therefore you concatenate with the next line's value-1 and get

`08-119 A
08-149 B
08-999 C`

You should read this table "up to and including 119, use A"

Comment: it does work, as the VLOOKUP() has a fourth parameter that can be TRUE or FALSE for exact match or best match. Worst case you need to add an extra line with very high weight. - If your best match is the other way around, you can concatenate the columns from consecutive lines (after sorting them) so `08-100: A` would mean _up to_ that use A, not _after that_.

Comment: Feel free to believe that. I am doing this at least once a week, and it works perfectly fine. Feel also free to come up with a better solution.

Comment: formatting prevents me from responding...

Comment: You are correct, it was the concatenation formula.  I had to add Text() to add the leading zeros to each field and then concatenate them together.  I bow to your Excel prowess.  Thank you!